# Javascript send image

Tags: javascript, ajax

In ajax I got it working but in javascript.

Ajax

```
        // Get base64URL
         var base64URL = canvas.toDataURL('image/jpeg').replace('image/jpeg', 'image/octet-stream');
         AJAX request
          $.ajax({
             url: 'https://url/ajax.php',
             type: 'post',
             data: {image: base64URL},
             success: function(data){
                console.log('Upload successfully');
             }
          });
```

In JavaScript

```
var request = makeHttpObject();
request.open("POST", "https://url/ajax.php", true);
request.send(base64URL);

request.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (request.readyState==4 && request.status==200) {
        console.debug(request.responseText);
    } else {
        console.debug(request.responseText);
    }
};
```

JS uploads to server image with 0 kb.
Should it append in image file base64 ? That's why it is 0? Tried several things searching but still not working.

Comment: We've got the [`Fetch API`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API) now for making async requests. It will make your code cleaner. You can see [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch) how to supply headers or a body to your request. Or do you absolutely need to use your `makeHttpObject` function ?

Comment: Not absolutely makeHttpObject. Just trying to make it work